# Openshot Default Project No Sound

Tags: sound, openshot

running Ubuntu 16.04 and Openshot Default Project, downloaded from the PPA, has no sound. Tried several files, none work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out, for some reason, pulse audio was muting python.  I went to System Settings, Sound, Applications, and Python was muted.  By un-muting it, sound began to work on Openshot.